# How to configure NGINX to serve Directus to Nuxt 3 app in Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nuxt.js, nginx-reverse-proxy, directus

I have a Docker container that runs 3 services: NGINX, Nuxt3, and Directus 10.8.
I am struggling to get a reverse-proxy to work correctly. I can successfully map Nuxt to "/", but I'm hitting error when mapping Directus to any route (but for argument's sake let's say "/admin"). It appears to partially work at least, but Directus returns a load of errors:
[image: directus errors]
Nuxt isn't hot-reloading either, I guess I need to also reverse proxy port 24678 for Vite, but I'm unsure how to do that. 
*How do I expose Directus on "/admin" correctly and will that allow Nuxt to consume it (specifically with directus-nuxt)?*

All services are contained in subfolders with their own docker-compose.yml files and the whole stack is run from a docker-compose.yml at root level:

```
/
|__docker-compose.yml
|__nuxt
| |__docker-compose.yml
| |__Dockerfile
| |__ # ...nuxt specific files
|__directus
| |__docker-compose.yml
| |__Dockerfile
| |__ # ...directus specific files
|__nginx
| |__Dockerfile
| |__default.conf
```

```
# /docker-compose.yml
version: "3"

include:
  - nuxt/docker-compose.yml
  - directus/docker-compose.yml

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - nuxt
      - directus
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - stack

networks:
  stack:
```

```
# /nuxt/docker-compose.yml
version: "3"

volumes:
  node_modules:
services:
  nuxt:
    container_name: nuxt
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
      - "24678:24678"
    volumes:
      - .:/src
      - node_modules:/src/node_modules
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    networks:
      - stack
```

```
# /directus/docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  directus:
    container_name: directus
    image: directus/directus:10.8.3
    ports:
      - 8055:8055
    volumes:
      - ./extensions:/directus/extensions
    environment:     
      PUBLIC_URL: "http://localhost:8055"
      # ...directus env variables - key, secret, db connection etc
    networks:
      - stack
```

```
# NGINX config
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://nuxt:3000;
    }

    location /admin {
        proxy_pass http://directus:8055;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have simplified your setup to get this working. You can generalise to your specific use case. In the interest of transparency, I know nothing about Directus, so I'm winging that part.

File layout for this to work would be:

```
├── docker-compose.yml
└── nginx
    └── nginx.conf
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - directus
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - stack

  directus:
    container_name: directus
    image: directus/directus:10.8.3
    volumes:
      - ./extensions:/directus/extensions
    environment:     
      PUBLIC_URL: "http://localhost:8055"
      ADMIN_EMAIL: "admin@example.com"
      ADMIN_PASSWORD: "d1r3ctu5"
      KEY: "255d861b-5ea1-5996-9aa3-922530ec40b1"
      SECRET: "6116487b-cda1-52c2-b5b5-c8022c45e263"
    networks:
      - stack

networks:
  stack:
```

The environment variables appear to be essential to get the Directus container running happily.

You don't need to expose port 8055 since presumably you won't be accessing Directus on that port from the host.

`nginx/nginx.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /directus/ {
        proxy_pass http://directus:8055/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr;
        add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

        proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
        proxy_send_timeout 30s;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

I've specified `/directus/` as the location for the Directus service. You can choose anything here *except* `/admin/` it would seem, presumably since that generates some sort of redirect loop (Directus already uses the `/admin/` path). Somebody more knowledgeable about NGINX might advise here.

Go to http://127.0.0.1/directus/. You'll immediately be redirected to http://127.0.0.1/directus/admin/login.

[image]

Comment: sadly this doesn't work for me:
[emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "directus" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:6
nginx     | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "directus" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:6  
 and the page can't be reached. If I change proxy_pass to http://localhost:8055/ I get a 502 with the error:
[error] 20#20: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.23.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /directus/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8055/", host: "localhost"

Comment: Apologies, I can't seem to get comment markdown to work

Comment: Are you using the `docker-compose.yml` I provided?

Comment: Sorry, I spoke too soon. I started afresh from your code rather than adapting my own and it works. /directus loads the login page but with no CSS & logging in returns a blank page and a few errors. I'm guessing that's out of your wheelhouse?  
I've also added Nuxt but it's accessible on all routes not just "/".  Here's my nginx.conf addition:  
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://nuxt:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

Comment: Aha! Great news. Okay, Directus login would require you to set up credentials. This is not part of the original question. You've added Nuxt: does that work?

Comment: I have Directus credentials and a db set up, and if I expose :8055 I can login & all works as expected.
Nuxt works fine, but it's just being exposed on any arbitrary route as opposed to "/" exclusively and it can't see the directus API (but that's getting into potentially different territory).

Comment: OK, thanks some help on Discord I've resolved the directus issue - I needed to update PUBLIC_URL to reflect that I have directus in a subfolder.
I'm still unclear on the Nuxt issue though!